# java streams: accumulated collector

Tags: java, java-stream

Currently, that's my code:

```java
Iterable<Practitioner> referencedPractitioners = this.practitionerRepository.findAllById(
    Optional.ofNullable(patient.getPractitioners())
        .map(List::stream)
        .orElse(Stream.of())
        .map(Reference::getIdPart)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
    );
```

As you can see, I'm using `this.practitionerRepository.findAllById(Iterable<String> ids)`, in order to get all using a single communication with database.

I was trying to change it using this:

```java
Optional.ofNullable(patient)
    .map(org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.Patient::getPractitioners)
    .map(List::stream)
    .orElse(Stream.of())
    .map(Reference::getIdPart)
    .collect(????????);
```

How could I use `this.practitionerRepository.findAllById(Iterable<String> ids)` into a custom collector in `collect` method?

Remember I need to get all entities at once. I can't get them one by one.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and ensure that the variables you use are never `null` in the first place. And then, get rid of the `Optional`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collector<T,A,R> downstream,                                                              Function<R,RR> finisher)` specialized collector for that.

1. Make a list of IDs using the Collector.toList() collector and then
2. Pass a reference `practitionerRepository::findAllById` to convert from `List<String>` to `Iterable<Practitioner>`

Example:

```
Iterable<Practitioner> referencedPractitioners = Optional.ofNullable(patient)
      .map(Patient::getPractitioners)
      .map(List::stream)
      .orElseGet(Stream::of)
      .map(Reference::getIdPart)
      .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(toList(), practitionerRepository::findAllById));
```